# I've installed loki but i still have "Install RELEASE" app installed(like live session)

Tags: release-loki

when i have installed loki my installation finish with an error at installing grub(that i've fixed later on live session), but app install RELEASE is installed(i don't think this app should exists on fully-installed system, or not?).
I don't know if the error with grub have cause this but, after all, this is only a little issue, i'm writing this to inform developers.

Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that a faulty installation would result in the installer not being removed at the end of the installation process.

To remove it, open up Terminal and execute

`sudo apt remove ubiquity`

This command will prompt you for an administrative password (`sudo`) and instructs the system package manager (`apt`), to remove the installer (`ubiquity`)

Comment: Ok, thanks, but this the only thing that installer do after grub-install or there are something else?

Comment: @mac12 If you have an installed system, Ubiquity's job is done :)